# Strange errors when linking to libmariadb

Tags: mysql, macos, cocoa, mariadb, libmysql

I'm currently develop an Objective-C library that links to the MariaDB C connector. I believe there is a problem with the library, though.

Every time I execute my code I get very strange errors on the console. The `-(id)init` method of my library calls `mysql_init(NULL)` to initialise the library but as soon as I return from `-(id)init` I get the following errors in the console:

`Object 0x10643df70 of class XXX autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking - break on objc_autoreleaseNoPool() to debug`

Thing is, there is no multithreaded code being executed and if I run the same `- (id)init` without the call to `mysql_init(NULL)` the errors disappear. I believe the libmariadb library is causing these errors to appear. I don't get why though.

Do I need to build it with any special command line switches? Am I calling the right methods? I obviously used the MySQL online documentation as a guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was busy with other stuff for a while. I've since updated MariaDB to the latest version and, as far as I can tell, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add this anytime you have a new thread:

```
@autoreleasepool {

//enter code here
}
```

Comment: I did, still doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried latest revision from launchpad?
Also try to build libmariadb with -DUNDEF_THREADS_HACK and
CMAKE_USE_PTHREADS:BOOL=OFF)